# How to parse HTML to a string template in Python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I want to parse HTML and turn them into string templates. In the example below, I seeked out elements marked with `x-inner` and they became template placeholders in the final string. Also `x-attrsite` also became a template placeholder (with a different command of course).

**Input:**

```
<div class="x,y,z" x-attrsite>
  <div x-inner></div>
  <div>
    <div x-inner></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Desired output:**

```
<div class="x,y,z" {attrsite}>{inner}<div>{inner}</div></div>
```

I know there is HTMLParser and BeautifulSoup, but I am at a loss on how to extract the strings before and after the `x-*` markers and to escape those strings for templating.

---

Existing curly braces are handled sanely, like this sample:

```
<div x-maybe-highlighted> The template string "there are {n} message{suffix}" can be used.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` can handle the case:

- find all `div` elements with `x-attrsite` attribute, remove the attribute and add `{attrsite}` attribute with a value `None` (produces an attribute with no value)
- find all `div` elements with `x-inner` attribute and use [`replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) to replace the element with a text `{inner}`

Implementation:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="x,y,z" x-attrsite>
  <div x-inner></div>
  <div>
    <div x-inner></div>
  </div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div', {'x-attrsite': True}):
    del div['x-attrsite']
    div['{attrsite}'] = None

for div in soup.find_all('div', {'x-inner': True}):
    div.replace_with('{inner}')

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<div class="x,y,z" {attrsite}>
 {inner}
 <div>
  {inner}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also, how to escape strings like "{hostname}" in the HTML which would conflict with python templating?

Comment: @aitchnyu sounds like a thing that should be handled separately, may be with a regex. Do you have an example input for this case? Thanks.

Comment: @aitchnyu in this example you basically want to replace `{n}` with `{{n}}` and  `{suffix}` with `{{suffix}}`, right?